# API Endpoint for Creating Users in G Suite (with Signup URL)

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there an API endpoint that generates signup links for new G Suite users to sign up and set their own passwords upon Account creations instead of the current flow?

We're using the following [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) which seems to only allow us to

1. Set a default password for the new users
2. Send it across to their inbox
3. Enforce changePasswordAtNextLogin

Doing it via the UI seems to generate the said URL so we're wondering if it's possible to do the same via API instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is an endpoint for that. Why would you want to do this? Why not using the UI directly?

Comment: Ah. Hmm. Cause we automate our Applications' User Management.

Comment: You could create an application to let users set their own passwords when creating the user via [Users: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert), but I don't know if this would be appropriate for your situation.